# Pointwise boundedness

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, uniform-convergence

I know if a real valued function $g$ is continuous on a closed and bounded interval $[a,b]$, then it is bounded. However, I am not sure whether the following holds for sequences of functions:

$\textbf{Q1}:$ Consider a sequence of real valued functions $g_{n}$ on $[a,b]$. Does it follow that {$g_{n}$} is point-wise bounded?

$\textbf{Q2}:$ If we assume further that {$g_{n}$} converges uniformly to $g$. Do we get uniform boundedness of {$g_{n}$} on $[a,b]$?

Comment: In question 1, do you make any additional assumptions about the sequence $\{g_n\}$? Like that it converges to anything?

Comment: @Nick: Yes, the {$g_{n}$} converge uniformly on $[a,b]$, but in Q1, I am just curious to know whether we can infer the point wise boundedness of $g_n$ without knowing that they converge uniformly.

Comment: Well, remember that a convergent sequence of real numbers is bounded.

Comment: @Nick: You're right! Since the {$g_n$} are uniformly convergent, that implies that they are point wise bounded, and therefore, for a fixed $x_{0}\in [a,b]$, $g_{n}(x_0)$ is a convergent sequence, and therefore it is bounded. Thanks for pointing this out. How about Q2? I am very positive that it should be uniformly bounded, but a rigorous proof eludes me.

Comment: It's enough that the sequence $\{g_n\}$ converges _pointwise_ for it to be pointwise bounded.

Answer (score 1):

1. is definitely false. Just take $f_n(x) = nx$ restricted to
   $[a,b]$.
2. is not necessarily true since, as is the case with sequences of numbers, you don't have to worry about the head of the sequence. All sorts of things can happen before you start converging. However, for infinitely many terms you'll need $g_n$ to be uniformly bounded otherwise you won't even get pointwise convergence to a continuous $g$.